# Finding and changing a page's slug

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way  from  the WordPress dashboard to find the slug assigned to a page and to change the value?  It looks like the value under Title might be the slug.  Is this the case?

Thanks.

Comment: That would be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is the slug - you can just click edit to change it.

Note that all slugs must be unique. So if you get a -2 etc once you save your slug it means that it is already in use.